# Why I don't see created directory when browsing Android phone from desktop?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I am developing an Adobe Air app for Android. I test it on a real Android device.

My app is creating a directory like this

```
var recordsFolder: File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("records");
file.createDirectory();
```

And this directory exists for Air (`recordsFolder.exists == true`)

But when I try browsing the Android device from a USB-connected desktop, I don't see that folder. How I can create folders and files that can be seen from a connected desktop?

Comment: What kind of USB connection are you using? ADB? Samba? Something else?

Comment: I mean simple connect for non-programmers. I just connect an Android device to desktop and browsing that device from windows explorer as disk.

Comment: You are just not looking at the right place. This is hardly a code question.